# Create Modal in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I want to create a modal that when clicked to element then modal active.but my code work just for one element.maybe i will have a lot of modal in my project.

```js
$('#mdl').on('click' ,  function () {
  $('.modaldiglog').addClass('show').fadeIn("fast");
})
$('#cancel').click(function () {
  $('.modaldiglog').removeClass('show').fadeOut("fast");
})
```

```css
.modaldiglog {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
  display: none;
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  width: 780px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 80px auto;
  background-color: #fff !important;
  height: auto;
  height: 80%;
  box-shadow: 14px 16px 13px -13px #696767;
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box .modal-header {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box .modal-header.delete-modal {
  border-color: #f00;
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box .modal-header.primary-modal {
  border-color: #70B9E8;
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box .modal-header.warning-modal {
  border-color: #d9aa28;
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box .modal-header.success-modal {
  border-color: #57a957;
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box .modal-header.defualt-modal {
  border-color: #ccc;
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box .modal-header .modal-section-title {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 8px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box .modal-header .modal-section-title h5 {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box .modal-header .modal-title {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 17px;
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box .modal-header .modal-title h1 {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box.modal-header .close-modal {
  color: #0E0C0C;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: url('../Content/Images/close-modal.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: 10px 6px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 30px;
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box .modal-header .close-modal:hover {
  background-position: 10px -36px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 36px;
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box .modal-header .modal-action {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 11px;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box .modal-header .modal-action .button.large {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box .modal-header .modal-action .button.color .btn-text {
  color: #000;
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box .modal-header .modal-action .button.large .fa {
  background: transparent;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box .modal-header .modal-action .button.large .fa.defualt {
  color: #000;
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box .modal-notification {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #efefef99;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.5);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.5);
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box .modal-notification .modal-notification-content {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 7px;
  color: #878787;
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box .modal-notification .modal-notification-content .modal-notification-successtext {
  color: #41ae55;
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box .modal-notification .modal-notification-content .modal-notification-successtext:before {
  font-family: fontawesome;
  content: '\f00c';
  padding-left: 7px;
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box.modal-notification .modal-notification-content .modal-notification-dangertext {
  color: #c43c35;
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box .modal-notification .modal-notification-content .modal-notification-dangertext:before {
  font-family: fontawesome;
  content: "\f05e";
  padding-left: 7px;
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box .modal-notification .modal-notification-content .modal-notification-warningtext {
  color: #d9aa28;
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box .modal-notification .modal-notification-content .modal-notification-warningtext:before {
  font-family: fontawesome;
  content: "\f071";
  padding-left: 7px;
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box .modal-notification .modal-notification-content .modal-notification-primarytext {
  color: #269CE9;
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box .modal-notification .modal-notification-content .modal-notification-primarytext span {
  /*font-family: fontawesome;
  content: "\f110";
  padding-left: 7px;*/
  margin-left: 10px;
}

@keyframes fa-spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

.modaldiglog .modal-box .modal-body {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: justify;
  height: 75%;
  padding: 3px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 9px;
}

.show {
  display: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="mdl">modal</button>
<div class="modaldiglog">
  <div class="modal-box">
    <div class="modal-header success-modal">
      <a href="#close" class="close-modal"></a>
      <div class="modal-section-title">
        <h5>unit personel</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-title">
        <h1>create personel</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-action">
        <a href="#" class="large color  button" id="cancel"><span class="fa fa-ban defualt"></span><span class="btn-text">cancel</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="large color  button"><span class="fa fa-check success"></span><span class="btn-text">enter info</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-notification">
      <div class="modal-notification-content">
        <span class="modal-notification-successtext"><span class="fa fa-spinner fa fa-spin"></span>loading...</span>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <h3>modal body</h3>
      <h3>modal body</h3>
      <h3>modal body</h3>
      <h3>modal body</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xdymjxtn/

Comment: Please don't use a workaround for the fiddle link restriction and place all relevant code within the question. If jsFiddle goes down your question will be unanswerable.

Comment: You may also want to google 'jquery modal' as there are literally hundreds of libraries to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as mentioned there are literally hundreds or libraries that already do this, and probably better with more features too, but if you really want to do it "your way", you could just add a class and id to each dialog?

e.g.

```
$('#mdl1').on('click' ,  function () {
  $('.modaldiglog.dialog-1').addClass('show').fadeIn("fast");
});
$('#cancel1').click(function () {
  $('.modaldiglog.dialog-1').removeClass('show').fadeOut("fast");
});

$('#mdl2').on('click' ,  function () {
  $('.modaldiglog.dialog-2').addClass('show').fadeIn("fast");
})
$('#cancel2').click(function () {
  $('.modaldiglog.dialog-2').removeClass('show').fadeOut("fast");
})
```

and change your markup accordingly, so `<div class="modaldiglog">` becomes `<div class="modaldiglog dialog-1">` and so on

`<button type="button" id="mdl">modal</button>` becomes `<button type="button" id="mdl1">modal</button>`

Updated your jsFiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/xdymjxtn/1/